# How to get correct nested enumeration numbering?

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem

I have the following MWE which has nested numbered lists. I am trying to reference a particular item. However, in the MWE given below instead of 1.3 it only gives the child list number, 3. The parent list number is missing. How do I get the entire item number with the parent number?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{\small{~\protect{\theenumi}}}},leftmargin=*]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.}]
        \item Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
        \item Aenean massa.
        \item \label{abc} Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.}]
        \item Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
        \item Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
            \item Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
            \item Integer tincidunt~\ref{abc}
            \item Cras dapibus.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Vivamus elementum semper nisi.
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.}]
        \item Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
        \item Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.
        \item Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference format for a enumerate list is using `\arabic` by default -- this is the reason why `3` is displayed and not `1.3`.

Use `ref={\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*}` as an option to the 2nd level `enumerate` list, this explicitly forms the reference as a combination of first level (`\arabic{enumi}`) and 2nd level (`\arabic*). If you prefer the bold version of the first level numbers, then say`\theenumi`instead of`\arabic{enumi}`.

Since this has to be done for every 2nd level, it is much more convenient to use the `\setlist[enumerate,2]` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\arabic*.},ref={\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*}}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{\small{~\protect{\theenumi}}}},leftmargin=*]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
        \item Aenean massa.
        \item \label{abc} Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
        \item Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
            \item Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
            \item Integer tincidunt~\ref{abc}
            \item Cras dapibus.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Vivamus elementum semper nisi.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.
        \item Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.
        \item Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]